# NodeJS read partial stream

Tags: node.js, child-process, node-streams

I have a NodeJS child process that on invocation calculates a unique pid (used by redis)

I and console logging it (e.g: `console.log('PID: ' + pid)`)

In the parent I call `spawn(command, arg, {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'], detached: true})`

Some things I tried:

1. Close the child processes stdout and pass it to a function (that returns a promise) and then

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    inputStream.on('data', (i) => {
      const isPidString = RegExp('/^PID:.+/g').test(i.toString('utf8'))
      console.log('isPidString', isPidString)
      if (isPidString) {
        console.log('found string')
        console.log('i', i.toString())
        const pidValue = parseInt(i.toString('utf8').split(': ')[1])
        console.log('pidVal', pidValue)
        inputStream.destroy()
        resolve(pidValue)
      }
    })
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject()
    }, 5000);
  });
```

Somehow it doesn't work. My question is: how do i listen to a stream (thats going to run nonstop) for just one specific console.log() that I'm concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Was able to figure this out
The code largely works, heres what was required:

1. Clone the child processes stdout (where we want to read data from)
2. read the string (convert to string using utf-8 encoding)
3. When the output matches a regex string you use string manipulators to extrac the value, destroy the stream and resolve.